# online radio in background on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uikit, background-process

I'm developing ALARM app and want to play online radio on alarm (for an example at 5:00pm) (sure when app in background mode). How can I do it ?

I know one app - TuneIn radio - in this app it works fine! But they show interesting alert "Please do not disable GPS Location".
I've try just locate position in background - it "eat" battery a lot. Is it possible to use another way ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of Local push notification

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Sure. But localpush can not play live-stream audio.. There is problem here...